# Delete selected text from content posts without deleting post itself (Wordpress)

Tags: mysql, regex

I've just learnt how to delete posts based on specific keywords in the title to execute with MySQL. Now I am trying to learn how to execute a similar script that will search post content and delete the following HTML code:

```
<input id="website_url" class="c7" type="text" value="this text changes" />
```

The value itself changes but so long as the script deletes everything inclusive up to the /> it will work.

This is what I've used before regarding the post titles

```
DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title REGEXP '\\1970-01-01 01:00:00'
```

I know the above has no relevance but the bit I enter with regards to what I want to delete is where the struggle for me comes from

Comment: Is that the exact html code to delete in all cases or are some of the parts variable. E.g. could it be `class="d6"`? Please provide several different sample inputs and show the desired result in each case. Try to achieve a [mcve]. For that a few lines of "create table ..." and "insert ..." would be helpful, which represent suitable test databasse content.

Comment: MySQL does not have an easy way.  MariaDB's has `REGEXP_REPLACE()`.

Comment: The only variable is the value. Everything else will stay the same, including the class.

Answer (score 0):

I propose:

```
select * from toy;
with key(string1) as (select '<input id="website_url" class="c7" type="text" value="')
update toy set html =
(   select
        substr(html,0,instr(html, (select string1 from key)))
        ||
        substr(substr(html,4+instr(html, (select string1 from key))),
               instr(substr(html,instr(html, (select string1 from key))), '" />'  )
              )
)
where html like '%'||(select string1 from key)||'%';
```

Basically

- update only where the fixed part of the searched html occurs,
  `where html like '%'||(select string1 from key)||'%';`
- update by concatenating the string before and the string after,
  `update ... set html = ...||...`
- avoid using long repeated strings with a CTE,
  `with key(string1) as (select '...')` -> `(select string1 from key)`
- some sqlite magic on strings, `instr(...)`, `substr(...)`
- slightly ugly, hard-coded what should be length of second string,
  `4+`

Comment: Thank you.

How will it react to changing values? Will it just delete all values associated with the code you've entered there.

The explanation you've given is actually far too advanced for me to understand. Would you mind telling me what I may need to edit in that code if I was to run that?

Comment: Could you make a [mcve], so that we can conveniently talk about the same thing? I know SQLite better than mysql, there I would ask you to use the `.dump` command from command line tool. As far as I know, in mysql, the same is provided by the dedicated mysqldump command line tool. In the end, what I want is a line of `create table wp_posts ...` and enough lines of `instert into wp_posts values (...)`. Then you can simulate a `select * from wp_posts` as you want it after the successful processing of the desired query.

Comment: I don't have any working code at the moment to achieve this objective. 

My question relates to what you've proposed and the variable which is text in the post that changes. I will give you a real example from the problem. This is the HTML that exists in several hundred currently published posts that needs to be deleted. The URL itself is what changes - it's a link back to another site. But the formatting the URL is within is consistent throughout, My approach was - scan the post to find the formatting (which is static), and then delete the URL.

Comment: Here is the code:

<input id="website_url" class="c7" type="text" value="https://www.newswise.com/articles/midlife-depression-may-stem-from-tension-with-mothers-and-siblings-iowa-state-study-finds" /> 

This is always the same across all posts:

<input id="website_url" class="c7" type="text" value=

But this isn't

value="https://www.newswise.com/articles/midlife-depression-may-stem-from-tension-with-mothers-and-siblings-iowa-state-study-finds"

But the domain is the same.